# Vue.Js Not Sending Files To Backend

Tags: php, vue.js

Im using vuejs and laravel to try and be able to upload multiple files but after assigning the array of files from the input to a formData it appears nothing happens.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <form id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" v-if="isInitial() || isSaving()">
        <div class="dropbox">
            <input type="file" multiple id="upload-input" @change="uploadFile($event)" :disabled="isSaving()">
            <p v-if="isInitial()">
                Drag your file(s) here to begin<br> or click to browse
            </p>
            <p v-if="isSaving()" v-cloak>
                Uploading (X amount of) files...
            </p>
            <p v-if="isSaved()" v-cloak>
                Image Saved!
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            Status: {
                CurrentStatus: null,
                Initial: 0,
                Saving:  1,
                Success: 2,
                Saved:   3,
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.setInitial();
        },
        methods: {
            setInitial(){
                this.Status.CurrentStatus = this.Status.Initial;
            },
            uploadFile(event){
                let formData = new FormData;
                let length = event.target.files.count;
                let files = event.target.files;

                for(let x = 0; x < length; x++){
                    formData.append("files[]", files[x]);
                }

                console.log(formData);

                this.CurrentStatus = this.Status.Saving;

                axios.post('/upload/files', formData).then(x => {
                    console.log(x);
                });
            },
            isInitial(){
                return this.Status.CurrentStatus === this.Status.Initial;
            },
            isSaving(){
                return this.Status.CurrentStatus === this.Status.Saving;
            },
            isSuccess(){
                return this.Status.CurrentStatus === this.Status.Success;
            },
            isSaved(){
                return this.Status.CurrentStatus === this.Status.Saved;
            },
        }
    })
</script>
```

In the uploadFile method after i set the formData using the for loop i console.log it returns an empty `formData{}` object. But when i console.log the `files` variable it returns an array of all the pictures that ive uploaded.

So i think the error is with my formdata object and how im setting it but im not sure, ive never messed with formdata and im not super experienced with JS.

**My Question**

Why isnt the formdata object setting the data.

Comment: Where do you send these files?
Because if you use php, here https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-uploader/blob/master/server/php/index.php is an example with a fileupload extension that can help you to compare with your solution

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let length = event.target.files.length
```

instead of...

```
let length = event.target.files.count
```

Comment: Thats a very keen eye thanks for the spot, although it hasnt fixed the problem formdata on the frontend still displays nothing, on the backend howver it picks up an array of 2 empty objects

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple issues.

```
let formData = new FormData;
```

should be

```
let formData = new FormData();
```

and you need to specify headers

```
axios.post('/upload/files', formData, {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
}).then(x => {
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: Hey ive changed my code to the above, and also changed formdata to `new FormData()` but i still get two empty arrays back

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

> let formData = new FormData(event.target);

In function as:

```
uploadFile(event){
   let formData = new FormData(event.target);
    console.log(formData);

  axios.post('/upload/files', formData).then(x => {
     console.log(x);
 });
}
```